# get the elements from list which is prefix/suffix by any other character

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I have one list which contain so many elements. Some of elements is prefix/suffix by any alphaNumeric character.

```
list1 = ["sign","xxsignzz","xxsign", "signzz","Design", "abc.sign.abc", "SIGN", "siGn"]
list2 = ["sign"]
```

I want list3 in which i will have elements like

```
list3=["xxsignzz","xxsign","signzz","Design","abc.sign.abc"]
```

I should get all value of sign prefix/suffix by anything in list3.

Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
[li for li in list1 if list2[0] in li and len(li)!=len(list2[0])]
```

---

```
['xxsignzz', 'xxsign', 'signzz', 'Design', 'abc.sign.abc']
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
lower = [l.lower() for l in list1]
list3 = [el[0] for el in zip(list1, lower) if el[1] not in list2]

>>> ['xxsignzz', 'xxsign', 'signzz', 'Design', 'abc.sign.abc']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
list1 = ["sign", "xxsignzz","xxsign", "signzz","Design", "abc.sign.abc", "SIGN", "siGn"]
list2 = ["sign"]


output = [i for i in list1 for x in list2 if x in i and x.lower() != i.lower()]
print(output) # ['xxsignzz', 'xxsign', 'signzz', 'Design', 'abc.sign.abc']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

list1 = ["sign","xxsignzz","xxsign", "signzz","Design", "abc.sign.abc", "SIGN", "siGn"]
list2 = ["sign"]
ptrn = re.compile("|".join(list2) + r"\b", flags=re.I)
print([i for i in list1 if not ptrn.match(i)])
#--> ['xxsignzz', 'xxsign', 'signzz', 'Design', 'abc.sign.abc']
```

Answer (score 0):

The Pythonic way to solve this is by using [list comprehension](http:///home/ajit/kernel-207/SCP/903.0.0.908). I have handled if your `list2` has more than one element.

```
list1 = ["sign", "xxsignzz","xxsign", "signzz","Design", "abc.sign.abc", "SIGN", "siGn"]
list2 = ["sign"]

result = [i for i in list1 for j in list2 if j in i and len(j) < len(i)]
print(result)
```

The above list comprehension is equivalent to:

```
result = []
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if j in i and len(j) < len(i):
            result.append(i)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['xxsignzz', 'xxsign', 'signzz', 'Design', 'abc.sign.abc']
```